# Structuring/organizing a linked list of filesystem folders

Tags: c++, tree, directory, unreal-engine4, graph-traversal

> **TLDR**:
>
> I need to know how I can represent a filesystem using a linked-list
>   struct, when the node traversal is in a weirdly reversed depth-first,
>   alphabetical order, knowing only two things at a time:
>
> - The full file (or folder) path, and:
> - Is this node a file, or a folder?

**Details:**

UE4 supports built-in, cross-platform filesystem operations via [IPlatformFile](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/index.html).
For filesystem traversal, they've included the following methods:

- [`IPlatformFile::IterateDirectory`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/IterateDirectory/index.html)
- [`IPlatformFile::IterateDirectoryRecursively`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/IterateDirectoryRecursively/index.html)
- [`IPlatformFile::IterateDirectoryStat`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/IterateDirectoryStat/index.html)
- [`IPlatformFile::IterateDirectoryStatRecursively`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/IterateDirectoryStatRecursively/index.html)

My goal is to fill in the following structure:

```
struct FFolderNode
{
public:
    FFolderNode() : FFolderNode(nullptr, TEXT(""), TEXT("")) {};
    FFolderNode(const FString& Path, const FString& Name) : FFolderNode(nullptr, Path, Name) {};
    FFolderNode(FFolderNode *ParentNode, const FString& Path, const FString& Name) : ParentNode(ParentNode), Path(Path), Name(Name)
    {
        ID = FGuid::NewGuid();
    };

    // Makes it easier to identify, map & find this node
    FGuid ID;
    // The name of this directory
    FString Name;
    // The path of this directory
    FString Path;
    // The filenames this directory contains
    TArray<FString> FileNames;
    // The upwards directory (equivalent to the path "..")
    FFolderNode *ParentNode;
    // The subfolders (if any) contained within this directory
    TArray<FFolderNode*> ChildNodes;
};
```

The issue I'm having...
I pass my project's `Contents` folder path to `IPlatformFile::IterateDirectory`, and it does this:
[image]

Looks like alphabetical order? So I'm not sure where to start.
It seems like I need to be able to create nodes before creating & assigning their parents, and without any real prior knowledge of ownership, aside from the currently visited node being either a file or folder, and it's full path as a string.

[`IPlatformFile::FDirectoryVisitor::Visit`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/FDirectoryVisitor/Visit/index.html) is the recursive function called by `IterateDirectory`... The engine source seems to make an inline class which subclasses [`FDirectoryVisitor`](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Core/GenericPlatform/IPlatformFile/FDirectoryVisitor/) and overrides this method, so that's what I've done in my code:

```
FFolderNode UDSAssetManager::GetContentTree()
{
    static auto ContentPath = FPaths::ConvertRelativePathToFull(FPaths::GameContentDir());

    class FFolderVisitor : public IPlatformFile::FDirectoryVisitor
    {
    public:
        IPlatformFile& PlatformFile;

        FFolderVisitor(IPlatformFile& InPlatformFile) :
            PlatformFile(InPlatformFile), RootNode(nullptr), PreviousNode(nullptr),
            FolderDepth(-1), PreviousDepth(-1) {};

        FFolderNode *CreateRootNode(const FString& Path, const FString& Name)
        {
            VisitedNodes.Empty();
            if (RootNode != nullptr)
                delete RootNode; // TODO: Traverse entire tree, releasing memory for all child nodes

            TArray<FString> SubPath;
            Path.ParseIntoArray(SubPath, TEXT("/"));
            if (SubPath.Num() > 0 && SubPath[SubPath.Num() - 1] == Name)
                SubPath.RemoveAt(SubPath.Num() - 1);

            return RootNode = new FFolderNode(FString::Join(SubPath, TEXT("/")), Name);
        };

        virtual bool Visit(const TCHAR* FilenameOrDirectory, bool bIsDirectory) override
        {
            auto Path = FString(FilenameOrDirectory);
            auto Result = PlatformFile.IterateDirectory(FilenameOrDirectory, *this);

            if (RootNode == nullptr)
                return false;

            FFolderNode *ThisNode = nullptr;
            if (VisitedNodes.Num() < 1)
                ThisNode = RootNode;
            else
                ThisNode = new FFolderNode();

            auto TempPath = Path.Replace(*ContentPath, TEXT(""));
            TArray<FString> PathArray;
            TempPath.ParseIntoArray(PathArray, TEXT("/"));
            FolderDepth = PathArray.Num();

            //
            // DO SOMETHING here, even though RootNode is NOT guaranteed
            // to be the actual root of the tree... ?
            //

            PreviousNode = ThisNode;
            PreviousDepth = FolderDepth;
            VisitedNodes.Add(ThisNode);

            return true;
        };

        FORCEINLINE FFolderNode GetRootNode() const {
            if (RootNode == nullptr)
                return FFolderNode();
            return *RootNode;
        };

    private:
        FFolderNode *RootNode;
        FFolderNode *PreviousNode;
        int32 FolderDepth;
        int32 PreviousDepth;
        TArray<FFolderNode*> VisitedNodes;
    };

    FFolderVisitor FolderList(FPlatformFileManager::Get().GetPlatformFile());
    auto RootNode = FolderList.CreateRootNode(ContentPath, TEXT("Content"));
    FolderList.PlatformFile.IterateDirectory(*ContentPath, FolderList);

    return *RootNode;
}
```

How can I properly build a linked list with the way the engine traverses file structures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that calling `IterateDirectory` from within `FFolderVisitor::Visit` is actually causing the strange order of traversal. After creating a separate method to handle initialization of the root node, and calling `IterateDirectory` from there instead, the traversal occurs in the correct DFS order.